# How do you display in realtime how long a buffer has been alive in emacs

Tags: emacs, buffer

I've noticed that it's extremely useful to see, in realtime, how long a program has been running. I've just began using emacs but after much searching haven't found a way to do this if it is even possible.

Any help is much appreciated.

P.S. I'm well aware of profilers but that is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Your title asks about buffer uptime, but your question seems to ask for Emacs uptime. Which are you looking for?

Comment: I'm looking for buffer uptime. When I mean program, I mean running a program in a separate window in emacs à la C-c C-c.

Comment: `C-c C-c` is a very common keybinding. I have no idea which major mode you are referring to, or what you've got it set to. What command are you running? (Try `C-h k C-c C-c`.) As far as "buffer uptime", you'll likely need to start a timer on a hook somewhere...

Comment: Sorry, I've noticed that C-c C-c is the same in both common lisp and python (compile) so I thought it was pretty universal for programming in emacs. Ok, thank you, I'll look into that.